# How to use an IF (or other) statement in PHP to look for a MYSQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am pretty new to PHP so I apologise if this seems like a dumb question. I am using PHP code with a MYSQL database.

I basically have the code below which has an HTML menu with its link being generated by a PHP variable. This is for the home page(this file ends in "pg1"). I want the file to check in my MYSQL database if there is a document with the same name but ending in "pg2". I am creating two variables one with pg1($fpname1) at the end and another with pg2($fpname2). How do I then have it look in my database for a table with a name = $fpname2? I know that then if it finds the table I can put a "else" and then the html which I want to include in the menu link.

This is the relevant code so far:

```
$fpname1 = $web_user."ID".$web_number."webID_"."pg1".".php";
$fpname2 = $web_user."ID".$web_number."webID_"."pg2".".php";

?>
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="<?php echo $fpname1; ?>">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

thank you for any help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use the `mysql_num_rows` function.

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example") or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($fetch);
```

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/index.php

Comment: Just a heads up, you don't pass `$count` to the `mysql_num_rows` function, you pass the query result, so `$fetch` in this case.  See (the doc)[http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php]

Comment: `I want the file to check in my MYSQL database if there is a document with the same name but ending in "pg2".` He doesn't want to check a file. He wants to check whether a database row exists. He's new to php so he's mixing up the terminology. So therefore, I gave him code to check how much rows a query matches as a count, so he can check whether the _"file"_ exists, by reading the variable of `$count`. So no, I am actually right, giving a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE page LIKE '%variable%'`

Then you would check the amount of rows the query returned, if that number is greater than 0 at least 1 page was returned, else it was never found.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE page LIKE '%pg_.php'
```

this will select all pages ranging between `pg0` to `pg9`

Answer (score 0):

you have a information_schema database I presume. In that there is a table called TABLE. in that all the table_names are kept. so if u give a query in database information_schema:
SELECT table_schema FROM TABLES where table_name = example
if the table_schema  is null then there is no table otherwise there is the database the table is in.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your database setup is wrong.
You have to store all your pages in one table, not many.

You are suffering from the SQL injection as a direct consequence. As well as overcomplicated and unmaintainable code.